# How can I speed up this Keras Attention computation?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, vectorization

I have written a custom keras layer for an `AttentiveLSTMCell` and `AttentiveLSTM(RNN)` in line with keras' *new* approach to RNNs. This attention mechanism is described by [Bahdanau](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.0473) where, in an encoder/decoder model a "context" vector is created from all the ouputs of the encoder and the decoder's current hidden state. I then append the context vector, at every timestep, to the input.

The model is being used in to make a Dialog Agent, but is very similar to NMT models in architecture (similar tasks).

However, in adding this attention mechanism, I have slowed down the training of my network 5 fold, and I would really like to know how I could write the part of the code that is slowing it down so much in a more efficient way.

The brunt of the computation is done here:

```
h_tm1 = states[0]  # previous memory state
c_tm1 = states[1]  # previous carry state

# attention mechanism

# repeat the hidden state to the length of the sequence
_stm = K.repeat(h_tm1, self.annotation_timesteps)

# multiplty the weight matrix with the repeated (current) hidden state
_Wxstm = K.dot(_stm, self.kernel_w)

# calculate the attention probabilities
# self._uh is of shape (batch, timestep, self.units)
et = K.dot(activations.tanh(_Wxstm + self._uh), K.expand_dims(self.kernel_v))

at = K.exp(et)
at_sum = K.sum(at, axis=1)
at_sum_repeated = K.repeat(at_sum, self.annotation_timesteps)
at /= at_sum_repeated  # vector of size (batchsize, timesteps, 1)

# calculate the context vector
context = K.squeeze(K.batch_dot(at, self.annotations, axes=1), axis=1)

# append the context vector to the inputs
inputs = K.concatenate([inputs, context])
```

in the `call` method of the `AttentiveLSTMCell` (one timestep).

The full code can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/DylanModesitt/c54af5b5531c0d4cc57a8b5ab0733437). If it is necessary that I provide some data and ways to interact with the model, then I can do that.

Any ideas? I am, of course, training on a GPU if there is something clever here.

Comment: Can you post the output of using `tensorflow.python.client.timeline.Timeline` on some sample training epochs? Without good profiler data, it's essentially just shots in the dark to guess why. Better to gather direct evidence.

Comment: yeah, I can get on that in a little @ely.

Comment: Have you profiled your code? Guessing at where to optimize can be a fools errand. I like the Python line-profiler [kernprof](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler), and w/ Keras you could make use of the TF tools like [TensorBoard](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/summaries_and_tensorboard).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend training your model using relu rather than tanh, as this operation is significantly faster to compute. This will save you computation time on the order of your training examples * average sequence length per example * number of epochs.

Also, I would evaluate the performance improvement of appending the context vector, keeping in mind that this will slow your iteration cycle on other parameters. If it's not giving you much improvement, it might be worth trying other approaches.

Answer (score 1):

You modified the LSTM class which is good for CPU computation, but you mentioned that you're training on GPU.

I recommend looking into the [cudnn-recurrent](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/0fc33feb5f4efe3bb823c57a8390f52932a966ab/keras/layers/cudnn_recurrent.py) implementation 
or further into the [tf part](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2a705b9d1524a856cd4c36a53629f25de97aba65/tensorflow/contrib/cudnn_rnn/python/ops/cudnn_rnn_ops.py) that is used. Maybe you can extend the code there.